# completion-at-point in evil mode error

Tags: windows, emacs, emacs23, evil-mode

Why do I get the error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: completion-at-point
```

When I type :e (in evil mode), then use tab-completion to complete a file name, while using emacs 23 on windows.

I don't seem to get this error on linux, however I would like to have it working in windows as well.

My configuration is available at https://github.com/arafangion/emacs.d

Comment: Its unreasonable to ask to go thorough all your configuration by following a link. about error it clearly shows you dont have function called `completion-at-point`. IIRC its introduced in emacs 24.

Comment: @kindahero: I wasn't expecting you to 'go through all your configuration', I was basically saying 'it's there if you want to look at it'; incidentally, http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.2 mentions that function, and aha, I'm using emacs 23.1!  Please make an answer and if updating to emacs 23.2 fixes it, I'll accept it. :)

Comment: The issue does not occur in emacs 23.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self described. Emacs doesn't have the `completion-at-point` function. As @Arafangion pointed in comment to his own question, `completion-at-point` is introduced in 23.2.

Upgrading to 23.2 or higher is obviously one possible solution. Anther possibility is writing an work around for evil mode to not to call `completion-at-point`.